# Unable to flip Canvas on creation

Tags: javascript

I am working on the following code. Why am I not able to flip a Canvas on creation? I know I can do this using CSS but since I want to download the Canvas with filpped format so I think I need to create it in flipped mode.

```js
  var sampleImage = document.getElementById("ringoImage"),
    canvas = convertImageToCanvas(sampleImage);
   
   // Actions
   document.getElementById("canvasHolder").appendChild(canvas);
   document.getElementById("pngHolder").appendChild(convertCanvasToImage(canvas));
   
   // Converts image to canvas; returns new canvas element
   function convertImageToCanvas(image) {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = image.width;
    canvas.height = image.height;
    canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(image, 0, 0).scale(-1, 1);

    return canvas;
   }

   // Converts canvas to an image
   function convertCanvasToImage(canvas) {
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    return image;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Original Image</h2>
  <img src="http://img.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2007/07_03/naniflipAP2607_468x652.jpg" id="ringoImage" />

 <h2>Canvas Image</h2>
 <div id="canvasHolder"></div>
 
 <h2>Canvas -&gt; PNG Image</h2>
 <div id="pngHolder"></div>
```

Comment: The `drawImage` method returns `undefined`. It's not chainable.

Answer (score 0):

Three important things to do:
1) start the processing after the image is loaded (sampleImage.onload)
2) flip the canvas BEFORE adding the image
3) avoid to save tainted canvas using crossOrigin="anonymous" on the source img tag

```js
var sampleImage = document.getElementById("ringoImage");
sampleImage.onload = function() {
var canvas = convertImageToCanvas(sampleImage);
// Actions
document.getElementById("canvasHolder").appendChild(canvas);
document.getElementById("pngHolder").appendChild(convertCanvasToImage(canvas));
};

   // Converts image to canvas; returns new canvas element
   function convertImageToCanvas(image) {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = image.width;
    canvas.height = image.height;
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        context.translate(canvas.width, 0);
        context.scale(-1, 1);
        context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
    
    return canvas;
   }

   // Converts canvas to an image
   function convertCanvasToImage(canvas) {
    var image = new Image();
        image.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
    image.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        return image;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Original Image</h2>
  <img crossOrigin="anonymous" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/4c9ebeb9-8b9a-4adc-ad0a-238d9ae00bb5%2Fmdn_logo-only_color.svg?1535749917189%22;" id="ringoImage" />

 <h2>Canvas Image</h2>
 <div id="canvasHolder"></div>
 
 <h2>Canvas -&gt; PNG Image</h2>
 <div id="pngHolder"></div>
```